# Can't access variable from other class - tkinter

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm attempting to write a program in tkinter where the user clicks on a button with their name and a verification page shows it to them. The problem I'm having is that the variable is either resetting or I'm accessing it wrong:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 10)
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()


class DIS(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "program")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, contactQues, nameVerify):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

            self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Name Select",
                        command=lambda:           controller.show_frame(contactQues))
        button2.pack()


class contactQues(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.controller = controller
        global name
        name = StringVar()

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Your Name", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Bojangles", command = self.bojangles)
        button2.pack(pady=5)

    def bojangles(self):

        name.set("Mr. Bojangles")
        self.controller.show_frame(nameVerify)
    #
    #Many other names to select
    #

class nameVerify(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        namename = name.get()

        label5 = tk.Label(self, text = "Your Name:", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label5.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        labelcontact = tk.Label(self, text = namename, font = NORM_FONT)
        labelcontact.pack()

app = DIS()
app.mainloop()
```

So, in essence, what I want to happen is:
- Program runs and user presses "Name select", user selects their name, and the final page shows their selection.

I've tried messing with globals, textvariables for the `labelcontact` label, StringVar(), etc. and can't seem to peg this one down.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I doing something inherently wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I realize I could have shortened this a bit more. My bad.

Comment: Yes, please shorten this.  Describe in detail what is not getting set properly: "the label" is not sufficient, since you have several in the program.  Also put in some print statements to trace the values in question; this may show an erroneous flow.

Comment: This is an interesting problem... I initially thought it would be a very easy fix of switching `text=namename` with `textvariable=name`, which _should_ cause the labelcontact to autmatically update whenever `name` does. But for some reason it isn't.

Comment: Trace variable on gui but inside of another class function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making `name` an attribute of the `DIS` class. Then your StartPage and nameVerify instances can access it via their `controller` attributes. If you want `labelcontact` to update automatically whenever `name` does, use the `textvariable` attribute.

Additionally, you need to delete your `root = Tk()` and `root.withdraw()` lines. I don't know why, but as long as they're there, the labelcontact Label won't properly update. They don't appear to do anything in any case - hopefully they aren't crucial to your actual code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 10)

class DIS(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "program")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.name = StringVar()
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, contactQues, nameVerify):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

            self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Name Select",
                        command=lambda:           controller.show_frame(contactQues))
        button2.pack()


class contactQues(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.controller = controller

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Your Name", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Bojangles", command = self.bojangles)
        button2.pack(pady=5)

    def bojangles(self):

        self.controller.name.set("Mr. Bojangles")
        self.controller.show_frame(nameVerify)
    #
    #Many other names to select
    #

class nameVerify(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label5 = tk.Label(self, text = "Your Name:", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label5.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        labelcontact = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.controller.name, font = NORM_FONT)
        labelcontact.pack()

app = DIS()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I never thought of that. I was trying global `name` and everything, but never touched `DIS.` It seems to work as expected -- thank you a ton. +1

Comment: re: _"Additionally, you need to delete your root = Tk() and root.withdraw() lines. I don't know why,"_ - the "why" is because `DIS` is a subclass of `Tk`, and a tkinter program should only have exactly one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did have a feeling that had something to do with it. I had to add it to get some other portion of the full program to work, but I'll go back to that later and see how to solve that without that second instance. Thank you for the clarification as well.